# My NOT EXISTS is not turning out like it is supposed to

Tags: sql, database

I am working on a NOT EXISTS and it is not turning out like it is supposed to. There should only be 2 results that should have showed up but I got 18. I am supposed to find all book titles (as 'book title') that have not had any sales in the database. For some reason I think I am forgetting something in the query but I am not sure. I don't understand why it's not working correctly.

```
Select title AS 'Book Title'
From titles
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(Select ord_num
    From sales
    Where title = ord_num)
```

Comment: Can you provide the tables' fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are trying to find sales records where the title is the same as the order number, in your `EXISTS` clause. I suggest something like:

```
Select title AS 'Book Title'
From titles
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(Select ord_num
    From sales
    Where titles.title_id = sales.title_id)
```

Comment: well something like that I have to find book title that have not had any sales in the database.

Comment: Yes, but in order to do that what you *need* to do is find book titles that have no corresponding record on the sales table. What you appear to have been *trying* to do is return all titles if there are any records on the sales table where the sales record's title id has the same value as its order number - in other words, you are returning everything.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Select title AS 'Book Title'
  From titles
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(Select *
    From sales
    Where titles.title = sales.title);
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT title AS 'Book Title'
  FROM titles
EXCEPT
SELECT title AS 'Book Title'
  FROM sales
```